# source code management setting not saved in jenkins job configuration

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I Installed locally Jenkins 2.224 using war file.
I am trying to set a job to pull files from git as on the screenshot below.
but when I save my job and then click configure again - None radiobutton is selected and all git settings are lost. Did it happen to anyone else? I cannot find what is the reason for this issue.
[image]

Comment: If you are using `Apply` button, try `Save` instead - it worked for me couple of times. Other thing is that some forms don't work well with some web browsers - you may try different browser.

Comment: neither Apply nor Save actually saves this setting. Maybe that is related to using jenkins.war installation.... I reinstalled Jenkins as a windows service and now it works ok.

Comment: I am seeing this exact problem as well.  Just upgraded to Jenkins 2.224, Git plugin 4.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [bug in v2.224](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-61398) that has been fixed in the subsequent version. Upgrading to the latest version should fix your issue.